# Is there any possible ways/delegates to identify the state of input accessory view of a UITextView's keyboard

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextview, uikeyboard

In my native iOS app, I have a screen that contains a simple textview. I need to adjust the size/frame of the text view when keyboard appears. I've succeeded it with `UIKeyboardDidShowNotification` as below:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(myKeyBoardIsOnScreen:) name:UIKeyboardDidShowNotification object:nil];
```

And setting the frame on:

```
- (void)myKeyBoardIsOnScreen:(NSNotification*)notification {
    NSDictionary* keyboardInfo = [notification userInfo];
    NSValue* keyboardFrameBegin = [keyboardInfo valueForKey:UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey];
    CGRect keyboardFrameBeginRect = [keyboardFrameBegin CGRectValue];

    self.textView.frame = CGRectMake(self.textView.frame.origin.x, self.textView.frame.origin.y, self.textView.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height-keyboardFrameBeginRect.size.height-self.textView.frame.origin.y);
}
```

**Problem:** This looks ok for the first moment. But later I realised that the frame of the keyboard is with the height of its accessory view included. So when I hide the accessory view by dragging it down, the textview appears to be broken.

**Hence can anyone suggest me any possible ways/delegates to identify the state of input accessory view of a textview's keyboard (like: Input accessory view is shown/hidden,etc.)**

NB: I need the accessory view. Hence I don't need to remove it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Register as an observer for the `UIKeyboardDidChangeFrameNotification` to update your view's frame.

[Apple Docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIWindow_Class/#//apple_ref/c/data/UIKeyboardDidChangeFrameNotification)

Comment: Wow...!!! Thank you very much Colin. I really missed that. Thanks for the support.... :)